# There is any impact to share point farm if we install SQL Server 2012 Service Pack 3

Tags: 2013, sql-server-2012, update

There is any impact to share point farm if we install SQL Server 2012 Service Pack 3 and it will make any changes to sharepoint configuration databases and content dbs.

we have below sharepont installed
Update for Microsoft SharePoint Enterprise Server 2013 (KB2986213) 64-Bit Edition 
 15.0.4753.1003 Installed

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The SharePoint 2013 with SP1 is supported with SQL Server 2012 SP3, so there is not impact on the farm, but this operation will require an outage.

So, it's recommended to

- Apply this operation first on a test farm before applying it directly to production.
- Apply this operation out working hour.
- Take a backup of all SQL Database.

Comment: we have Configuration database version:15.0.4753.1000 is it support right?

Comment: Yes,The 15.0.4753.1000 is September 2015 CU , that mean you have SharePoint with SP 1 that supported

Answer (score 0):

There should not be an issue while applying the updates to SQL server as SharePoint version you are is fine with SQL 2012. Now here are some practices you need to follow while apply the SQL updates.

- Stop the IIS on the SharePoint Server
- Stop / unscheduled  the Search Crawls
- stop / Unscheduled  the User profile Sync
- Stop if you have any custom tasks on sharepoint servers
- Stop the SharePoint timer and Admin services
- Backup the SQL server( all the databases)

Now apply the SQL updates, once done then start / schedule above services.

If you dont want to deal with this, you can simply shut down the SharePoint servers, once done with sql updates then come back and start them.

Reason behind this, when you applying the SP3 to SQL during that time frame if user access SharePoint and SharePoint will make a connection to sql but databases are not ready for that which can cause the corruption.